# Newbie:invalid literal in python

Tags: python

I am writing some code to gain practice programming Python. The code is as follows:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

string ='''
73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450'''.replace('\n','')

sum1 = 1
lis = [0,1,2,3,4]
lis2 = list()
while(1):
    for j in range(5):
        sum1 *= int(string[ lis[j] ])
    lis2.append(sum1)
    sum1 = 1
    for k in range(5):
        lis[k] = lis[k] + 1
    if lis[4] == 999:
        break
lis2.sort() 
print lis2
```

The program is used to find the greatest product of five consecutive digits in the 1000-digit number.

But the program didn't work! An error

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

occured when I ran the program!

I am a newbie to python!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is simple: Python triple-quote strings include the line ending.  There is a "newline" character at the end of each line, and `int()` is not happy.

Easiest solution is to use the string `.replace()` method to remove the non-wanted newline characters.  We use `"\n"` for a newline:

```
string = """
012345
242432
234323""".replace('\n', '')
```

After I make that change, your program still doesn't work, but that particular problem is gone.

EDIT:
To improve your program, I suggest you read up on "slicing" of strings in Python.  You can use slicing to grab 5 characters at a time from the input string.  Also, Python can loop over a string with an ordinary `for` loop, so you can get a 5-character slice and loop over it to multiply the five digits together.

Answer (score 4):

**Help teach you how to fish for yourself:**

The error says "what you are passing in to `int()` isn't actually an integer", so how about before you try to `int()` it, you print it. `print string[ lis[j] ]`. That should help you debug the problem.

**Gives fish anyway:**

The problem is you are trying to turn a new line character (`\n`) into an integer. As @steveha suggested use `.replace()`

Comment: This tip about printing is a good one.  Also, I usually print a string bracketed in characters that make any white space (including a newline) obvious:  `print("DEBUG: +++%s+++" % string[ lis[j] ])`

Comment: @steveha Use `repr`, `%r`, `{!r}` if you want whitespace and unprintable characters to be shown explicitly.

Comment: @agf, I agree `repr()` is good for that.  I write more C code than Python (I'd prefer the reverse) and the `+++` bracket is something I use in all languages.  But for Python `repr()` is even better; in this case it would have printed `\n` and you can't get clearer than that.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to specify your string is like this. The smaller strings will be concatenated at compile time and no further processing is needed at runtime

```
mystring = (
    '73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934'
    '96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843'
    '85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511'
    ...
    '71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450')
```

Spoiler(rot13). This will give the digits that make up the greatest product

```
>>> zlqvtvgf = znc(vag, zlfgevat)
>>> qrs cebq((n,o,p,q,r)): erghea n*o*p*q*r
... 
>>> znk((zlqvtvgf[v:v+5] sbe v va enatr(yra(zlfgevat)-4)), xrl=cebq)
[9, 9, 8, 7, 9]
```

Comment: Oh, I meant to put something about this and I didn't get to it.  Thanks for this.  To anyone reading: the parentheses tell Python to keep looking for more stuff, and Python is smart enough to take multiple strings in a row like this and join them all together into one long string.  Something similar to this works in C, but in C you don't need the parentheses (but you do need a final semicolon on the very end).